# Latex Table write Text beside \hline

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I want to add text beside the **\hline** line in order to structure my table more accurately. The following picture illustrates what I want, the code represents the table. Anyone has some ideas? I'd appreciate a lot.

[image]

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \caption[..]{..} \label{tab:trigger}

    \begin{tabular}{l | r}  

    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{PARAMETER}}     &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{VALUE}}      \\ 
    \hline \hline

    STA window                  &       $\SI{5}{s}$         \\
    LTA window                  &       $\SI{100}{s}$       \\
    Trigger level               &       4.4                 \\
    De-trigger level            &       1.5                 \\
    \hline

    Filter                      &       $3-15$ Hz           \\
    Pre-event time              &       $\SI{60}{s}$        \\
    Extract duration            &       $\SI{120}{s}$       \\
    Minimum trigger duration    &       $\SI{5.8}{s}$       \\
    Freeze LTA window           &       no                  \\

    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Rather than on the side, I suggest putting the text as a supplementary row after the rule: `\multicolumn{2}{c}{text here}`. Avoid the vertical rule, that serves no purpose, and all will be well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please always post complete documnents showing all packages used (your example required `siunitx`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \caption[..]{..} \label{tab:trigger}

    \begin{tabular}{l | r}  

    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{PARAMETER}}     &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{VALUE}}      \\ 
    \hline \hline

    STA window                  &       $\SI{5}{s}$         \\
    LTA window                  &       $\SI{100}{s}$       \\
    Trigger level               &       4.4                 \\
    De-trigger level            &       1.5%       
\smash{\raisebox{-8pt}{\rlap{\quad here!!}}}          \\
    \hline
    Filter                      &       $3-15$ Hz           \\
    Pre-event time              &       $\SI{60}{s}$        \\
    Extract duration            &       $\SI{120}{s}$       \\
    Minimum trigger duration    &       $\SI{5.8}{s}$       \\
    Freeze LTA window           &       no                  \\

    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'll consider your suggestions for the next time. :)

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the text should be in a supplementary row below the rule: just remove the vertical rule, which serves no purpose. I added also the analog for the first table chunk.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\sisetup{range-phrase=--}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l r}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{PARAMETER}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{VALUE}} \\ 

\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{First part} \\

STA window               & \SI{5}{s}           \\
LTA window               & \SI{100}{s}         \\
Trigger level            & 4.4                 \\
De-trigger level         & 1.5                 \\

\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Second part} \\

Filter                   & \SIrange{3}{15}{Hz} \\
Pre-event time           & \SI{60}{s}          \\
Extract duration         & \SI{120}{s}         \\
Minimum trigger duration & \SI{5.8}{s}         \\
Freeze LTA window        & no          \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you don't need `$...$` around `\SI{...}{...}` and that in ranges the unit should be repeated, so the input is not mistaken for “three minus fifteen hertz”.

Compare it to the output of David's answer

[image]

Comment: Very nice suggestions,thank you for that. Actually, it matches my desires even more. :)